# Python Regex separating numbers after a dash

Tags: python, regex

This is the regex I am using:

```
date = "1981-89"
date = re.findall(r'\d+', date)
```

if the date is 1981-89 this returns [1981],[89]. What do I add to the regex to ignore anything after the dash including the dash itself?

Thanks!

Comment: why not  just split the string and take what you need?

Comment: `date.partition('-')[0]` would be a lot more efficient than using Regex.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. I am trying to learn regex. I can easily parse the string but I am trying to learn something new. Thanks!

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\d+)-', date)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you **need** to use regular expressions, use the first element of a `match` search:

```
re.match(r'(\d+)', date).group() # matching using parenthesis in regex
```

Comment: I agree with this. It seems to me that English Grad is asking for the first matching item, and thus should be using `match` or `search` rather than `findall`.

Comment: @bmhkim Yes I changed from `findall` to `match`. Never really understood the difference between `match` and `search`.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it  with `re.sub` :

```
>>> re.sub(r'-.*','',date)
'1981'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What do I add to the regex to ignore anything after the dash including the dash itself?

You can use this regex:

```
date = "1981-89"
date = re.match(r'\d+(?=-)', date).group()
// 1981
```

`(?=-)` is a lookahead that makes sure we are only matching number that is followed by a hyphen.